# download from Android or Windows .deb package to install offline?

Tags: deb

I would like to know if there is any way to download the official .deb files to install software in Ubuntu while offline. I am currently using an Android operating system, so preferably I would need to download it with this operating system and then install it offline. I specifically need to download the cd/dvd burning software whose name is k3b, but taking a look on the Ubuntu website I see dependencies and so on and in the end I don't know what to download.

Some explanation?

Updated:

My doubt is that if you have to download each of the dependencies listed in the search result, it is too tedious a process. Is this necessary? How to know what dependencies to download? Can you download multiple dependencies at once without having to download one by one?

[Result K3b package search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AIGD.png)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to download .deb files of any of the packages that are in the default Ubuntu repositories from the official [Ubuntu Packages Search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/) website. Ubuntu Packages Search supports all currently supported versions of Ubuntu and also supports the 20.04 development release.

[image: Ubuntu Packages Search]

The search results for a package also include a list of all the dependencies that are required to install that package. For example there are 40 dependencies listed for the k3b package because it's a KDE package, whereas there are only 15 dependencies for brasero CD/DVD burning application for GNOME, many of which are already installed in Ubuntu by default.

After clicking the  <kbd>Search</kbd>  button another page will open.

[image]

Click the red hyperlink in the above screenshot.

[image]

Click the red architecture link (marked by the black arrow in the above screenshot) to open the download mirrors page, select a nearby mirror, and download the .deb file. Please note that you can only download the .deb files one at a time, but to save time you can choose a similar application that has fewer dependencies, in this case Brasero. Most of the dependencies required to install Brasero are already installed by default in Ubuntu. You can check if the dependency packages are installed by running a command that has the following form:

```
apt policy first-package next-package ... last-package
```

...where the italicized package names in the above command are replaced by the package names of the list of dependencies. As usual for apt commands `apt policy` can take multiple arguments.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer me! Updated the post.